# Mac OS X Lion - Xcode components simulator location

Tags: download, iphone, xcode, documentation, simulator

When we downloaded Xcode 4.5.1, to test applications in older simulators we installed it from `Settings->Downloads->Components`

Now there is Xcode 4.5.2 available. Again we need to download simulators for that Xcode ? or is there any location where those simulators stored similar to Documentation.

In 2nd image below we can see location for documentation but in 1st image selecting simulator doesn't show any location of installation.

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

Now there is Xcode 5 available. Again we need to download simulators for that Xcode ? or is there any location where those simulators stored similar to Documentation.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode5 the simulators are downloaded in a temporary folder  *download-and-install-cache-dstroot*:

```
/private/var/folders/mb/yf1qy9bx7wg5dl01lzkvbytm0000gp/T/download-D39FB382-2540-4F2E-B8EC-6940A468CEAE-7723-000031655DACE7B0/download-and-install-cache-dstroot/Xcode.SDK.iPhoneSimulator.6.1-6.1.dmg
```

And I bet the simulator is linked to the compiler in a way that you need a new iOS6 simulator even if you had one for XCode 4.5.1.

Use Munki and Reposado to *roll your own* if you want to save downloading for each Mac.

Comment: Thax I got it. Awarded bounty. One more question, can we do something like I have already download .dmg file of simulator and just place that somewhere that folder where it download and than Xcode continues installing ?

Answer (score 3):

The download location changes every time you start the download.

```
find /private/var -name Xcode.SDK.iPhoneSim*
```

will reveal the download directory.

The download is restarted every time you click "Install", that is, any previous download is discarded (what a waste with 600 MB+ file size).

Although the downloaded file is a DMG, I still don't know how to copy from one machine to another to prevent downloading.

Comment: When I run this command in Terminal it says permission denied. Any idea ?

Comment: Any idea, I am still wondering about this error of permission denied.

Answer (score 2):

**The location of dmg file downloaded by Xcode is placed here.**

> *~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads*